# Elaboration on Lagrange's algebraic approach to calculus?

Tags: integration, derivatives

In lectures 4 and 8 of NJ Wildberger's differential geometry series, he presents an algebraic method of taking the derivative of a polynomial that was apparently devised by Lagrange. He briefly mentions the fact the same can be applied to the general differentiable function without showing how. The only way I could think to do this would be to write out the Taylor expansion of the function about a point but this would require evaluating the derivative at the point which is what I wanted to do in the first place. Thus my first question is: can this method actually be used to evaluate the derivative of an arbitrary differentiable function? And my second question is: is there any related algebraic method for the evaluation of integrals and the proving of The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Can you state or provide a link to Lagrange's method that does not require watching a video?

Comment: @zyx sorry I haven't used this account in a while, a skim of this should suffice

Comment: @zyx http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fhomes.chass.utoronto.ca%2F~cfraser%2FLagrangealgvision.pdf